# Python: Is there any way to sort a dictionary by integer value

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any way to find value number in a dictionary, say 3, without knowing the key in python?

I do know that dictionaries do not have an order.

All i can get are arbitrary elements using 
dict[dict.keys()[0]]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i:i[1])` i believe this is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if i understand correctly, you are looking for all keys with the value 3. That can be achieved by itering through the keys and comparing:

```
output = []
for key, value in dict.items():
    if value == 3:
        output.append((key, value))

print(output)
```

If you wanna simply sort by integer values, try:

```
sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda i:i[1])
```